# Multiple child Actors in akka

Tags: scala, akka

I have a situation in which one particular `Actor` needs to use 2 instances of an other `Actor`, each having different parameters. These sub-actors use other 'named' actors and obviously it cannot be handled because there cannot be multiple actors running at the same time, with the same 'name'. How this can be done?

Comment: Why do they need to have the same name?

Comment: Because, the same actor is used more than once, hence they will have the same name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Im not wrong the name of an Actor is unique in the context of the parent. So if the two instances of the actor you create have different names, then they can use other named actors.

I stand to be corrected though.

Comment: other same named actors?